# Dynamically Add / Remove multiple input fields in PHP with Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is the HTML of my form

```
<div class="crcform">

          <h1>Internship Details</h1>

          <form name="internship_details" id="intership_details">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                <tr>
                <td>
          <!--div class="top-row"-->
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Company<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="company[]"/>
            </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Project<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="project[]"/>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Duration<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="duration[]"/>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Key Learning<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="key_learning[]"/>
          </div></td>
          <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
         </tr>
         </table>
         <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit"  class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
          <!--div class="top-row">
          <div class="field-wrap">
          <button class="button button-block" name="submit" id="submit"/>NEXT</button> 
          </div-->

          </form>
          </div>
```

this is javascript of dynamically add/remove form

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    $('#add').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><div class="field-wrap"><label>Company<span class="req">*</span></label><input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="company[]"/></div><div class="field-wrap"><label>Project<span class="req">*</span></label><input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="project[]"/></div><div class="field-wrap"><label>Duration<span class="req">*</span></label><input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="duration[]"/></div><div class="field-wrap"><label>Key Learning<span class="req">*</span></label><input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="key_learning[]"/></div></td></td><td><button name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
    });
    $(document).on('click','.btn_remove', function(){
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#row"+button_id+"").remove();
    });

    $('#sumbit').clic(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"internship_details.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:$('#internship_details').serialize(),
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                $('#internship_details')[0].reset();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

this is the php code to store data in database

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

$number = count($_POST["company"]);
if ($number > 0){
    for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++){
        if(trim($_POST["company"][$i]) != ''){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO internship VALEUS('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["company"][$i]."')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        }
    }
    echo 'Data Inserted';
}
else{
    echo "Enter Name";
}
?>
```

I'm unable to store the value in database. Can anyone tell me where im going wrong?
Can you also tell me what its insert query will be because i'm adding more than one column in a row. So help me with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a lot of spilling errors in the code

Here is the working version: given that all files are at the same directory

html and javascript:

```
<div class="crcform">
        <h1>Internship Details</h1>
        <form id="internship_details">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!--div class="top-row"-->
                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <label>
                                Company<span class="req">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="company[]"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <label>
                                Project<span class="req">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="project[]"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <label>
                                Duration<span class="req">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="duration[]"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <label>
                                Key Learning<span class="req">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="key_learning[]"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit"  class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var i = 1;
            $('#add').click(function(){
                i++;
                $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><div class="field-wrap"><label>Company<span class="req">*</span></label><input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="company[]"/></div><div class="field-wrap"><label>Project<span class="req">*</span></label><input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="project[]"/></div><div class="field-wrap"><label>Duration<span class="req">*</span></label><input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="duration[]"/></div><div class="field-wrap"><label>Key Learning<span class="req">*</span></label><input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="key_learning[]"/></div></td></td><td><button name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
            });

            $(document).on('click','.btn_remove', function(){
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
                $("#row"+button_id+"").remove();
            });

            $('#submit').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    url: "internship_details.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: $('#internship_details').serialize(),
                    success:function(rt)
                    {
                        alert(rt);
                        $('#internship_details')[0].reset();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

php code:
connection.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'crc');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

internship_details.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['company']); $i++)
{
    $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['company'][$i]);
    $project = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['project'][$i]);
    $duration = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['duration'][$i]);
    $key_learning = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['key_learning'][$i]);

    if (empty(trim($company))) continue;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO internship(company, project, duration, key_learning)
            VALUES('$company', '$project', '$duration', '$key_learning')";
    mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
}

if(mysqli_error($connect))
{
    echo "Data base error occured";
}
else
{
    echo $i . " rows added";
}
?>
```

Note that additional data sanitization and validation may be required based on your requirements.

Comment: done with all the changes which you and hulothe have told me to do. but still data is not getting store in the database.

Comment: Did you change the column names

Comment: You also misspelled the form id in the beginning of html. change it to internship_details

Comment: And there is no need for the name attribute in the form element

Comment: which column name? column name in the database are same as of variable name.

Comment: now im getting the error: NOTICE undefined variable: connect in internship_details.php on line 10. WARNNG mysqli_real_escape_sting() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in internship_details.php on line 10.

Comment: this means that the data base connection variable is not defined, please post the code in the connection.php file

Comment: and same goes for 12,13 and 14

Comment: connection.php: <?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db('crc') or die ("cannot select");
?>

Comment: Here is another error you are using mysql in the connection and mysqli in the code

Comment: Use this in the connection file:  $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "crc");

Comment: i did that to.. still getting the same error

Comment: i even try this: 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "crc";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

Comment: You must use $connect not $conn, $connect is the variable used in the code

Comment: still now working..:(

Comment: Add this after the for loop and tell me what it returns: echo mysqli_error($connect);

Comment: still getting the same error..:( whats your mail id? let me mail you full code

Comment: wait I'll reproduce your script and get you the working code

Comment: Have a look I updated the answer

Comment: Mark the answer as correct if the code worked

Answer (score 0):

You have mispelled `click` in `$('#sumbit').clic(function(){` and `VALUES`  in `INSERT INTO internship VALEUS`.

Comment: Can you also tell me what its insert query will be because i'm adding more than one column in a row. So help me with this.

Comment: @RajdeepRatan `INSERT INTO table(row1, row2, row3) VALUES(value1, value2, value3)`

Comment: can you tell me what this line if(trim($_POST["company"][$i]) != '') and this line mysqli_query($connect, $sql); are doing?

Comment: on clicking submit nothing is happening. Data is not getting store in the database.